# Recyclerview - how to disable vertical scrolling on item swipe (fling)

Tags: android, swipe, android-recyclerview

Simple question - how to disable recyclerview scrolling while swiping its item? I created OnTouchListener inside recyclerView item view holder, but it catches swipe events only if user makes straight horizontal line. Otherwise recycler list is scrolling. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I am not using `ItemTouchHelper` because it doesnt quite do what I want. I solved this by checking the source to it and finding the call to:

```
getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
```

Call that when you determine the user has started swiping (i.e., moved more than a few pixels). Then don't forget it to call it again with `false` when the swipe is done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the opposite problem. If you are using the ItemTouchHelper, do this

```
mItemTouchHelper.startSwipe(myViewHolder);
```

This would force the swipe instead of the scroll.